# How Do I Disable IIS Error Pages And Handle Errors In Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, iis, error-handling

I've been trying to disable IIS error handling so I can capture all errors in Global.asax.

I am running Windows 2012 with IIS version 6.2.

For example, when I navigate to a missing image file such as:

[www.mysite.com/thisimagesdoesntexist.jpg](http://www.mysite.com/thisimagesdoesntexist.jpg)

I get the IIS error page and my Global.asax does not capture the error.

I tried adding to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors existingResponse="Passthrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

And also, in Global.asax:

```
Server.ClearError()
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
```

However, the missing image error still is handled by IIS. Here is the code of my web.config and my Global.asax routine:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--Unobtrusive validation used JQuery-->
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <!--Enable Sessions and don't scroll a form when doing a postback-->
    <!-- clientIDMode="Static" ensures the ASP.net controls have the exact name specified in their ID tags
         This is important so CSS targets the correct IDs for styling. -->
    <pages enableSessionState="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="Static" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
    <!--Use cookies if enabled; use querystring if disabled-->
    <!--<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="20" />-->
    <!-- cookieless="AutoDetect" is adding a cookie parameter to the URL that was causing FastSpring posts to fail -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
    <!--Show detailed errors on the website while developing-->
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <!--Use Tracing-->
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" />
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
  </system.web>
  <!--
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Passthrough" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.0 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <compiler extension=".vb" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

  Dim Uri As Uri = New Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)

  Dim ex As HttpException = CType(Server.GetLastError(), HttpException)
  Dim httpCode As Integer = ex.GetHttpCode()
  Dim strErrorDescription As String = ex.Message.ToString

  Server.ClearError()
  Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True

  If httpCode = 500 Then
    Response.Redirect("~/error.aspx?type=globalerror&errdescription=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strErrorDescription) & "&url=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Uri.ToString))
  ElseIf httpCode = 404 Then
    Response.Redirect("~/404.aspx?type=globalhttp&errdescription=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strErrorDescription) & "&url=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Uri.ToString))
  Else
    'Let's see what other errors are picked up and logged. Perhaps we log these to a separate table?
    Response.Redirect("~/error.aspx?type=globalhttp&errdescription=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strErrorDescription) & "&url=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Uri.ToString))
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Requests for static files do not enter the asp.net route, but IIS goes to the corresponding folder to find resources. So that error page is thrown by IIS not asp.net application. IIS error page cannot be disabled. Unless you let the application read the image according to a certain physical path in the code and read failure throws an exception. Otherwise, requesting the image directly will only make IIS always respond to the error page.

Comment: If you know a little bit more about IIS/ASP.NET architecture, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis you will see static files and ASP.NET pages are handled by different handlers, so their errors are handled separately. Unifying business logic to handle both kinds of errors is more complex than you thought (no good solution from Microsoft at least).

Comment: My plan was to log all errors into an errors table in a database. Are you saying there’s no way to capture errors unless they actually occur in the asp.net code itself? If not, where would I go to run a report of what errors IIS has been encountering?